# Node.js Javascript Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have a Node.js HTTP server running which goes like this (simplified):

```
http = require('http');
help = require('./modules/help').run;
router = require('./modules/router').run;
m = {something: require('./modules/something')};

var server = http.createServer(router).listen(8001);
```

"help" is a set of functions-helpers, for example:

```
module.exports.run = {
  joinObjects: function(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var prop in obj2) {
       obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
    }
    return obj1;
  }
}
```

"router" handles the request (passes it further down and handles response to the client):

```
module.exports.run = function(req, res) {

  var urlPath = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

  switch(urlPath) {
    case '/something':
      requestHandler(req, res, 'something');
      break;
    ...
  }

  function requestHandler(req, res, handler) {
    var data = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    }
    req.on('end', function() {
      m[handler].run(req, data, function(response) {
        response.headers = help.joinObjects(config.responseHeaders, response.headers);
        res.writeHead(response.code, response.headers);
        res.end(response.data);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

The "handler" module/function runs the callback function and passes the response (code, headers and data) to it. The callback function then merges headers with a set of default headers that are set in the config file.

**THE ISSUE:** When there are two connections calling `help.joinObjects()` at the same time (that's my guess), `response.headers` property collides with the one of another user/connection and returns bad data. If I comment out the line that does the merging, this does not occur.

**THE QUESTION:** What's wrong with my approach to the "help" module? There is some kind of scope issue that I do not understand here.

Comment: Maybe that's because you merge headers from response into config? Does changing `help.joinObjects(config.responseHeaders, response.headers);` to `help.joinObjects(response.headers, config.responseHeaders);` solve your issue?

Comment: Hey! No, that's not the issue. The final `headers` property contains headers that should be sent back to a completely different client (scary!). They do not come from the config file. The issue is that some data that is supposed to be client-unique is actually being shared by two (or more) clients that happen to send request at the same time. I thought all the stuff is encapsulated well enough to not being shared between different connections but it turns out that it's not?..

Comment: But js runs in single thread, so there is no race conditions. Are you sure that my suggestion does not help? (sorry to ask again :) )

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue with your fix while the issue still occurs with my version. So your your suggestion may have fixed or hidden the problem but the question then is - HOW?.. At some point two distinct user connections must be accessing the same scope as neither `config.responseHeaders` nor `response.headers` contain the header that I can detect in my browser when returned. And that specific header is returned from a separate module that I am not accessing at that time. So I am pretty sure there is a scope issue in the code.

Comment: Ok, got it! config is in the global (or top, doesn't matter) and since JavaScript passes variables by reference, my joinObjects function modifies the global object's property (that is - config property) every single time it is called. My bad :(

Comment: Glad you spotted it :)

Comment: Have been stuck on this for something like 3-4 hours now. Thanks a lot! You made my day :)

Comment: You should post your solution... for example, did you EXTEND the objects before passing them?

Answer (score 0):

As **lazyhammer** pointed out, the problem was the order in which I passed objects into the helper function: `help.joinObjects(config.responseHeaders, response.headers)`.

Javascript passes variables by reference, so every time `help.joinObjects()` is called, it overwrites the config property instead of the user-specific object.